# Создание бесконечного цикла генерирующего произвольную последовательность символов из этого цикла

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var stringChars = new char[30];
    var random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
    {
        stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
    }

    var finalString = new String(stringChars);
    Console.WriteLine( finalString);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: И в чем проблема?В создании цикла? while(true){// ваш код}  вот вам бесконечный цикл

Comment: Проблема в том что мой код требует чтоб я вручную ввел длину строки,  и я не знаю как сделать без StringChars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string stringChars = string.Empty;  // я считаю не нужно в c# везде использовать var,а лучше явно указывать тип
        var random = new Random();
        int value = random.Next(0, chars.Length); // случайное число от 0 до длины вашей строки


        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) // в ручную ничего указывать не нужно
        {
            stringChars += chars[random.Next(chars.Length)]; // просто каждый новый символ дописываем в конец строки
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Длина {0} : {1}", value, stringChars);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: можешь пожалуйста помочь с написанием того, что мой якобы" второй акк попросил", это не мой 2й акк, а знакомого)

Answer (score 0):

Бесконечный цикл с произвольной последовательностью и длиной строки. Прерывание цикла по нажатию Esc.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var random = new Random();

    ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
    while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        var stringChars = new char[random.Next(20, 50)];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];

        var finalString = new String(stringChars);
        Console.WriteLine(finalString);

        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-> Done!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```